# Implementing rbind for a series of matrix

Tags: r

I want to bind a number of matrix which are result of a function. For the following example, I want to bind the result of `Myfn(m)` for `m<-(1:3)`

```
Myfn <- function(m){
  matrix <- m * matrix(1:6, nrow=2)
  return(matrix)
}
```

which is

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    2    6   10
[4,]    4    8   12
[5,]    3    9   15
[6,]    6   12   18
```

Any idea how to implement it in R?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> do.call(rbind, lapply(1:3, Myfn))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    3    5
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    2    6   10
[4,]    4    8   12
[5,]    3    9   15
[6,]    6   12   18
```

A short explanation: `rbind(x, y, z)` is equivalent to `do.call(rbind, list(x, y, z))`, where the second argument to `do.call()` is a **list** consists of function arguments you would normally pass to `rbind()`. And `lapply()` will apply your function to `1:3`, returning the sub-matrices in a list.

Answer (score 2):

You could also do:

```
 Reduce(rbind, lapply(1:3, Myfn)
```

If your matrices are of different sizes

```
library(plyr)
rbind.fill.matrix(lapply(1:3,Myfn))
```